# PDFsharp word wrap

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

How does one wrap text inside the rectangle using PDFsharp?

In my attempts the text still extends off the PDF's page. Here is what was tried:

```
rect = new XRect(20, 300, 400, 100);
tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Left;
gfx.DrawString("\t • Please call the borrower prior to closing and confirm your arrival time and the closing location. \n", font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
rect = new XRect(20, 320, 100, 100);
gfx.DrawString("\t • If the borrower needs to change the closing appointment time or date for any reason please have them call McDonnell Law Firm at 866-931-8793 \n", font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
rect = new XRect(20, 340, 100, 100);
gfx.DrawString("\t • Completed documents must be received same day. Fax back to 888-612-4912 or email ClosingDocs@appliedtechres.com \n", font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
rect = new XRect(20, 360, 100, 100);
gfx.DrawString("\t • Documents are to be returned via Fedex or UPS with shipping label provided. Documents must be dropped same day. \n", font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

This is what it is doing > [image]

Comment: What's the *problem*? Please be more specific.

Comment: I added a picture. The text is going off of the page. I have changed the width of the rectangles but it makes no difference.

Comment: I believe he meant "can't seem to understand..."

Answer (score 18):

From your code snippet I assume that `tf` is an object of the XTextFormatter class while `gfx` is an XGraphics object.

`XGraphics.DrawString` does not support line breaks.

`XTextFormatter.DrawString` supports line breaks.

The error in your code: you are calling `gfx.DrawString` where you meant to call `tf.DrawString`.

Comment: Pity, In VS2017 intelli-sense does not find a class called XTextFormatter :(  And class CText,, which is found, has no DrawString() method :(

Comment: Aah, had to add its location, in VB "imports PdfSharp.Drawing.Layout", to the code page to find it.  OK, so far, now :)

Answer (score 15):

This is my example which does the following:

1. defines a rectangle and draw a thin box to show the outline
2. places the text within the box, small logic handled to add margin (adding 5 px to X coordination and deduct the same 5px as width area of text.
3. XTextFormatter will be using to place the text within the defined rectangle.

**Example**

```
 PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
 PdfPage pdfPage = pdf.AddPage();
 XGraphics graph = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage);

 var tf = new XTextFormatter(graph);
 var rect = new XRect(25, 50, 200, 34);

 XPen xpen = new XPen(XColors.Navy, 0.4);

 graph.DrawRectangle(xpen, rect);
 XStringFormat format = new XStringFormat();
 format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near;
 format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near;

 XBrush brush = XBrushes.Purple;
 tf.DrawString("This is some text written in a textbox over three lines bla bla bla bla bla ffffffffffffffffffffdsdsdsd", 
               new XFont("Helvetica", 8), 
               brush, 
               new XRect(rect.X + 5, rect.Y, rect.Width - 5, 34), format);
```

How to save and run the example:

```
string pdfFilename = "firstpage.pdf";
pdf.Save(pdfFilename);
Process.Start(pdfFilename);
```

Comment: Doesn't write over 3 lines, but it does word wrap +1